# Bootstrap 3 - weird floating issue with 3 column responsive layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with a three column layout in bootstrap 3.

When in Full Desktop View, I have a standard 3 col layout, but on responsive, I have the 3rd column placed underneath and full width.

The problem I'm getting is that, on responsive, the 3rd column is becoming 100% height and overlapping the other 2 columns above.

See screenshots below.

I've replicated a simple example below.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-8"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-2"></div><!--full with on responsive view-->
</div>
```

Is this a known issue with bootstrap3? Or is my markup wrong?

DESKTOP LAYOUT
[image: fullwidth layout]

RESPONSIVE LAYOUT (the blue column is appearing over the top the green and red)
[image: responsive layout]

Cheers

Comment: Do you have custom CSS overriding Bootstrap? Seems to work as expected with just Bootstrap -- http://bootply.com/81978

Comment: no custom CSS. The layout is as plain as the code I posted. It won't work with just What I'm struggling to get my head around..

Comment: Sorry..I hit enter by mistake.. my col-sm columns don't add up to 12 so that's where the issues are arising from. But. I don't get it.. I thought the whole point of them was to make something like this achievable. I think I'm missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had another look over the docs. The answer is to use  a clearfix ie.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-8"></div>
  <!--clearfix here-->  
  <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2"></div><!--full with on responsive view-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-8"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2"></div><!--full with on responsive view-->
</div>
```

Comment: that will make the last column appear under the top two, which is what I'm trying to do, but I need it to be full width on reponsive (col-12)

Comment: any column class under 12 has 'float-left', so the above are both floated left, and the bottom isn't, that's where the problem comes from. And easy solution is to just float the bottom left. I didn't want to do this because it seems like I'm hacking bootstrap. I was looking for a cleaner solution

Comment: for doing this use col-xs-12 in large screen, but you remember that we have maximum 12 column grids. So if you are adding -12 this will override others in the same row class. So try to put in different rows.

Comment: they can't be in different rows because they're 3 columns, the row with always be 100% width, so they'll stack on top of eachother